# How to Set And Get Cookies in laravel Helper function. Function is in App/Http/Helper.php

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I'm trying to set and get cookies in laravel helper function which is inside App\Http\Helper.php. But its not working. I don't get an error but cookie is not set in the browser.

Here is my code...

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;
public static function getCookies() {
    Cookie::queue('Cookies', 'Set-Cookies', 100);
    return "Cookie::get('Cookies')";
}
```

While I'm using the same code in controller its working perfect. But's its not work in function....
What to do?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: No Error, But Cookies is not set on browser..

Comment: where are you calling this method?

Answer (score 1):

This issues could be because Cookie queuing is not enabled for requests.

It works in `controller` because of `web` `$middlewareGroups` in `App\Http\kernel.php` file. Your Controller is having `web` `middleware` applied to it.

So this code will work properly in `Controllers` where `web` `middleware` is applied to it.

Using `helper` function you can call common class function which is setting cookies.

Comment: I guess you have to use `class` or `middleware` for this feature.

Comment: Make your Helper.php same as your controller in which this code is working and put this method in Helper.php.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this late answer suits anyone who finds themselves on a case like this. As far as I know, you can't get that cookie with `Cookie::get` because `Cookie::queue` won't send the cookie to your browser until a response is sent. So, you'll have to wait to send the response, and then get the cookie on another method after the one you're showing.

To put an example:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

public static function createCookies() {
    Cookie::queue('Cookies', 'Set-Cookies', 100);
    return response()->json(['message'=>'Cookies created!'], 200);
}

//Call this method afterwards
public static function getCookies() {
     return response()->json(Cookie::get('Cookies'));
}
```

I hope it helps!